# when i try to run code in accident detector iam getting error in keras

Tags: python

iam getting error for the below code

**IAM GETTING FOR THE BEOW PYHTON CODE**

```
import cv2
image=[]
label=[]

c=1
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('/kaggle/input/cctvfootagevideo/videoplayback (online-video-cutter.com).mp4')
while True:
    grabbed, frame = cap.read()
    if c%30==0:
        print(c)
        resized_frame=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(frame, (img_height, img_width), interpolation='bilinear')
        image.append(frame)
        label.append(predict_frame(resized_frame))
        if(len(image)==75):
            break
    c+=1

cap.release()
```

**THE errror msg :**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-62bc6ff5f2d2> in <cell line: 7>()
      9     if c%30==0:
     10         print(c)
---> 11         resized_frame=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(frame, (img_height, img_width), interpolation='bilinear')
     12         image.append(frame)
     13         label.append(predict_frame(resized_frame))
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```